# Clear entered command in Intellij Idea Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

I work with Terminal in Intellij Idea and sometimes I find that the command I've just entered should be erased. In Windows or Linux I can use Ctrl+C to clear the command I've just entered, in Idea I should hold Delete or BackSpace to erase it. What is the similar keyboard shortcut in Idea? Or if there is no one by default, can it be set up?

Comment: BTW, in Linux Ctrl+U also clear current line and don't have side effects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My answer is specific to Windows as I don't have another platform handy at the moment.

If you open the Terminal tool window within IntelliJ IDEA to use the command prompt, and start typing a command, but realize that your command isn't what you want to do and want to erase it, you can use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to erase the current line. This isn't really an IDEA-specific shortcut, it's standard within the Windows command prompt.

If after running a command, you want to clear the commands you've run and their output from the screen, you can just run the `cls` command, which again is a standard command prompt feature.

Comment: I am using windows, so worked like a charm for me, thank you! As an addition, I can assume that on other platforms the trick will work with standard keys that clear the current command, except CTRL+C (for unknown for me reason)

Comment: I've been getting a couple downvotes on this and I'm not sure why… The Esc key still clears the line in Terminal for me in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.3.6 on Windows. What am I missing?

Comment: @user65839, Esc always switched to editor focus, at least in my version (2020)

Comment: @ShmuelKamensky I ran into the same thing. ESC would clear the line but also switch to editor focus. I fixed this by removing the 'Switch Focus to Editor' keymapping. Now it just clears the terminal line.

Answer (score 13):

For me and for version 2018.3 **Esc**, **Ctrl+C** and typing **cls** all don't really clear the terminal, it just scrolls down so you don't see anything other than the current input line, but you can scroll back up anyway.

This might be enough for most, but as soon as you search for sth in the console using Ctrl+F you also search the old content you were trying to get rid of.

This works as of version 2018.3:

**Ctrl + K (Default and Visual Studio Keymap)**

*Note: the terminal window must have focus!*

Comment: The shortcut seems to have changed to **Ctrl + L** (version 2019.3)

Comment: IntelliJ on Mac, Cmd+K in the terminal clears it.

Comment: @ChristophMuth OP asked about clearing only the current command, not the whole terminal window.

Comment: thanks. Cmd+K keys are working for MacOS intellij terminal. clear is useless command.

Answer (score 13):

To ***quickly find the shortcut*** to clear the current terminal session, the following should work in all operating systems:

1. `Right Click` (or similar) anywhere on the terminal window you want to clear,
   so that a context menu shows up.
2. `Clear Buffer` should be located somewhere near the bottom of this context menu. The current **keyboard shortcut** should also be visible.

Comment: Thanks so much. This has save me countless hours of searching.

Answer (score 6):

IntelliJ by default switches focus away from the terminal when you press **Escape**. This can be annoying if you are used to **cmd** behavior in Windows, where **Escape** clears the current command. To make IntelliJ work the same as Windows, go to:

```
Settings -> Tools -> Terminal > Configure terminal keybindings
```

Then remove **Escape** binding from `Switch Focus To Editor` (last option) - by right clicking the option and choosing `Remove Escape`. Now you can clear your current command by pressing **Escape**, same way Windows cmd works.

[image]

Comment: Best answer (for Windows) at least. Just reverts to the default ESC shortcut.

Comment: This is probably what causes this command does not clear terminal output in Intellij terminal. `printf '\33c\e[3J'` in which `\33c` means `ESC`. But it still does not work after I removing the `Escape` shortcut. Appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2):

to clear terminal :

- ctrl + L
- or: right click and choose Clear Buffer

Answer (score -1):

To clear the history just use command: history -c

Comment: the history command is used to clear the history of commands entered through bash. This has nothing to do with the Terminal tool in IntelliJ